# Unity is *always* visible, no matter what app I'm using

Tags: unity, launcher

I have used Unity for a bit, but I have never encountered this.

Any full screen (games, lock screen, etc) app, the Unity sidebar and the top bar are always visible. Thankfully, they don't work. However, working on a Netbook using a full-screen app and losing 5% of your screen is rather annoying.

(For some reason I can't post screenshots atm)

Is there any way this can be fixed? I am running 12.04

Comment: That's... odd. Also, you should be able to post screenshots.. No idea why you think you can't. What happens when you try?

Comment: It would be Ubuntu's refusal to make screenies in a fullscreen app or lock screen.

Comment: I have two suggestions. 1: Get some updates. 2: Try tweaking some settings using the "Ubuntu Tweak" - http://ubuntu-tweak.com/

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson Nope. I tried.

Comment: @FrankSlezak You should be able to use the Print Screen button on your computer, or use a built in screenshot program set at a delay.

Comment: print screen button is not working. delay is also not working.

Comment: *Bump* *Bump* *Bump*